# How to limit number of rows displayed in jasper report to just 5?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to make a change to jasper report template
[image: report template]

The fields 1 and 2 are rows of the data table of the jasper report. Grandtotal shows the total sum. Here, only top 5 rows of the results passed has to be shown but the grandtotal has to be sum of all the rows supplied. Currently. all the query results are passed into report. Thus it shows all the rows. How to change this template to show only top 5 rows and negate the rest. The grandtotal however should contain sum of all the rows. The template is below for reference. The template does not use group but just detail band.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="vehicle_most_frequent " language="groovy" pageWidth="540" pageHeight="720" columnWidth="500" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="00746fd2-b3ac-404d-9dd1-101d4ba25774">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="columnNameMap" class="java.util.Map"/>
    <parameter name="param" class="java.util.Map"/>
    <field name="1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="2" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="3" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <variable name="2_sum" class="java.lang.Float" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{2}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="2_percent" class="java.lang.Float" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{2}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="39" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="39" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="08c8dae3-4b33-4877-a71d-cd9669172164"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="13" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{param}.get("title")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="229" height="28" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FF8705" uuid="ccbec519-7ab3-4f43-a39c-9542aa5591f6"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{columnNameMap}.get(1)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="229" y="0" width="148" height="28" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FF8705" uuid="470b050f-1961-4549-bac3-ccb37880f14d"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{columnNameMap}.get(2)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="377" y="0" width="123" height="28" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FF8705" uuid="bc9d1557-ad50-4301-8c63-8345d5661a08"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{columnNameMap}.get(3)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="229" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d39709a4-ef29-4db6-a5a1-74d1dc5c3bdb"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="229" y="0" width="148" height="20" uuid="0af88c77-922f-40f4-8acf-71921f715a14"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" pattern="#,##0.00 %">
                <reportElement x="377" y="0" width="123" height="20" uuid="3692483a-4fe9-44a8-87d7-965ff4f7e2c4"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{2}?$F{2}/$V{2_sum}:0)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="229" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFF00" uuid="f72b8925-f6cd-4d5e-9617-63e971327211"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grandtotal]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="229" y="0" width="271" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFF00" uuid="a4e37752-e733-4ed5-823f-649eb0a2fa66"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{2_sum}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: @AlexK, the dupes are not perfect (since they are about page and size), I saw you have answered one mentioning the REPORT_MAX_COUNT, consider to reopen and answer this one with a full jrxml example. (if we can't find a better dupe).